# How to get PHP data into an HTML table

Tags: php, html

I am trying to view the multiplication table data in tables in html, but it does not work. I am trying to use "table" for the table format in html.

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php


<table>
<tr>
 <td>for($i = 0; $i<=9; $i++)
 {
<td>for($j=0; $j <=9; $j++)
{
  $product = $i * $j;
  echo $i . " X " . $j . " = " . $product . "<br>";
}</td>
 }</td>
</tr>
</table>

   ?>
</body>


</html>
```

How can i get PHP data into an HTML table?

Comment: You have to use `?>` and `<?php` to switch between literal HTML and PHP scripting. You can't put `<table>` inside a PHP block.

Comment: How can i get php data into html table?

Comment: Use `echo` or switch between PHP and literal mode with `?>` and `<?php`.

Comment: Any PHP tutorial should include examples of how to show data in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will print table from 1 to 10.

**Code :**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
           $p = $col * $row;
           echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**PS :** You can do little googling and get result.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i<=9; $i++)
{   
    for ($j=0; $j <=9; $j++)
    {
        $product = $i * $j; 
        echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td> X </td><td>" . $j . "</td><td> = </td><td>" . $product . "</td></tr>"; 
    }   
}

?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```